# How to deal with touch events interception for class hierachy (as opposed to view hierarchy)?

Tags: android, android-listview

I know how to deal with touch events interception to steal the touch events from the **child** views when necessary. However, this mechanics is for **views hierarchy**, not for **class hierarchy** (as well as the boolean returned by `onTouchEvent()`). Hence my question.

### The use case I'm facing

I'm currently trying to combine a custom pull-to-refresh ListView with a custom swipe ListView.
Basically, I created 2 classes that can work independently:

```
public class SwipeListView extends ListView {}

public class PullToRefreshListView extends ListView {}
```

To combine them, I made the swipe list extend the pull-to-refresh list, as follows. Is this a good solution to start with?

```
public class SwipeListView extends PullToRefreshListView {}

public class PullToRefreshListView extends ListView {}
```

**Now I would like to block swipe events when pulling to refresh, but I'm struggling to find a clean way to do so without adding too much dependency between the two classes.**

The current classes both work with touch events, using `onTouchEvent()`.

- Should I misuse the return value of `onInterceptTouchEvent()`/`onTouchEvent()` to inform the child class that the super class consumed the event?
- Should I tie the two classes by accessing the state of the super class from the child class? Is there a better solution that I missed?

Comment: have you tried something like `SwipeListView extends ListView` and `PulltoRefreshListView extends SwipeListView`?

Comment: @Ankit Popli Well as I said I tried the other way round, but I guess this does not differ much, I'll have to put some logic anyway somewhere to block the swipe feature.

Comment: Definitely you'll have to put some logic to block one while the other is in action. `Is this a good solution to start with?` Yes, according to me this should solve the purpose.